# customer-centered vs customer-centric

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between 'customer-centered' and 'customer-centric'? It seems to me that 'customer-centered' is plain and understandable.  I do not see any reason to replace it with 'customer-centric.'

Comment: No difference.  Like "customer oriented," they are business-babble buzz word designed to sell books to the credulous.

Comment: Whichever one your company's ad-speak people choose.

Answer (score 2):

I've done some further research and into more credible sources. Firstly, I think we can all agree that the term **customer centered** is synonymous with **[customer focused](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/customer-focused).** According to *Cambridge Online Dictionary:*

> Customer focused: paying great ​attention to the ​needs and ​opinions of ​customers.

The term **[Customer Centricity](http://knowledge.wharton.upenn.edu/article/peter-fader-on-customer-centricity-and-why-it-matters/)** was coined by Wharton Professor Peter Fader; and has a distinct meaning from **customer centered.**

> *Customer centricity means that you’re going to be friendly, provide good service and develop new products and services for the special focal customers — the ones who provide a lot of value for you — but not necessarily for the other ones. You need to pick and choose. Some customers deserve the special treatment, and if others want to buy from you, that’s great, but they are not going to be treated the same.*
>   -Peter Fader

Comment: I was of the mind of deadrat's comment, until you pointed out that *centered* is like a service company, where as *centric* might be one that is a retailer actually  concerned with customer satisfaction.

Comment: I would find BusinessDictionary.com's distinction between these two terms a lot more plausible if it also had entries for alternative orientations and emphases such as _business-centered_, _business-centric_, _profit-centered_, _profit-centric_, _shareholder-centered_, and _shareholder-centric_. But in fact it has entries for none of these terms, even though they are obviously alternatives to the two discussed here. I suspect that what we have here is not a systematic categorization of -centered and -centric orientations, but instead a couple of empty buzzwords that sound good to customers.

Comment: @Sven Yargs I've edited my answer to somewhat fix the faults you described in your above comment.

Comment: +1 for your extra effort in finding more-authoritative sources and for your civility in response to a rather hostile comment (by me). I stlll think that we are wandering in the land of marketing buzz here, but at least you have gotten us to the origin of "customer centricity" and identified a useful probable antecedent to "customer-centered" in "customer-focused." Well done.

Answer (score 0):

We generally use "centric" with Greek words: geocentric, heliocentric since it comes from the Greek "kentrikos" - "of the centre". We use "centred" with non-Greek words: Earth-centred, sun-centred, citizen-centred since it comes from the Latin "centrum" - "centre".

Comment: This rule sounds right to me, but I think the explanation is a bit imprecise. The suffix *-ic* is certainly a common sign of a Greek-derived word (although there are some *-ic* words that were formed on non-Greek bases). Both *centric* and *centre/center* ultimately come from Greek *κέντρον.* It was taken into Latin as *centrum.* The Oxford English Dictionary says that *centricus* is a "post-Classical" Latin word used by "1540 or earlier", so it seems plausible that *centric* also passed through Latin before entering English (the OED's first citation for *centric* in English is from "a1593").